# Silverstripe Log in User with php

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using the [Email Verified Member module](https://github.com/marijnkampf/SilverStripe-Module-EmailVerifiedMember) for SilverStripe.

What I want to do is, after user click the verification email, I want the user to be automatically logged in.

I have tried to modify directly into the module controller, I have a member instance, I have tried the ->logIn() method but it didn't work, this is a piece of the code, with ->logIn() being my addition:

```
if($request && $member = DataObject::get_one('Member', "\"Email\" = '".Convert::raw2sql($request->param('ID'))."'")){
        if ($member->VerificationString == Convert::raw2sql($request->param('OtherID'))){
            if (!$member->Verified) {
                $member->Verified = true;
                $member->write();
                $member->sendmoderatoremail();
                if( $member->logIn() ) {
                    print '<pre>';
                    print_r($member->logIn());
                    print '</pre>';
                    exit;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of Silver Stripe you are using. If it is ^4 Than it is:

`Injector::inst()->get(IdentityStore::class)->logIn($member);`